# Using Timber to render 3rd party plugin page templates

Tags: wordpress, plugins, twig, timber

I'm building a Wordpress site using the excellent Timber templating plugin.

I'm also using Sermon Manager plugin, which uses it's own [page templates](https://github.com/WP-for-Church/Sermon-Manager/tree/dev/views).

I can't figure out how to render the SM page templates through Timber.

[This page](https://thecommunitychurch.online/our-talks/) renders within the page.twig template, but clicking on the series title (top link) leads to an empty page, because it's trying to load the archive-wpfc_sermon.php template within the SM plugin directory.

I imagine its something like rendering Woocommerce page templates in Timber, but I can't work out how to adapt to SM:
https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/woocommerce/

Any help appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code [here](https://github.com/WP-for-Church/Sermon-Manager/blob/16ef8cf4c3501df43a72b19850800d09635421f1/includes/sm-template-functions.php#L701), you can overwrite the page templates by adding them to your own theme. This means it should be possible to create your own `archive-wpfc_sermon.php` in the root directory of your theme, and use that page to render your Twig views.